# Yahoo Store Catalog to Google Shopping Feed PHP Script

Tags: php, xml, csv, google-shopping

I'm trying to import my Yahoo Store catalog into Google Shopping. The Yahoo catalog exports as CSV but it needs to be an XML. I'm creating a PHP script to do the conversion. So far, I've created all of the appropriate elements, converting names and values as needed, but am having trouble with the shipping price element. It is self closing prior to the value, ie:

```
<g:price/>PRICE
```

instead of

```
<g:price>PRICE</g:price>
```

I'm fairly certain it's related to appendChild or nesting but I'm still learning and this is the first time I've worked with CSV or XML in PHP. I'd appreciate any recommendations or ideas in fixing this and cleaning up my messy code.

CSV Example (input.csv), only one product:

```
id,name,caption,product-url,c4-tab4-local,c4-tab5-local,condition,orderable,price,sale-price,code,label,ship-weight
"10auodgrwibl","5 PACK Magnet for Military Style Steal Ammo Can","Our Military Ammo Can Magnets will stick to any side of a standard issue military ammo can like the one pictured. Use these to mark your can(s) so you don't have to open them up to see whats inside. Great for preppers! Each magnet measures approx. 3.54"" x 2.05"" or 90 x 52 mm

Wholesale/Dealer Inquires welcome.","http://www.example.com.com/10auodgrwibl.html","https://sep.yimg.com/ca/I/yhst-057809732878263172244949_2487_75897626","Ammo Can Magnets","New","Yes","12.98","4.99","PI-ACM10MMOD","Example Manufacturer","0.07"
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Set Store Info here
$storetitle = "Example Store"; // Store/business name
$url = "http://www.example.com"; // store URL
$tagline = "Online Store"; // store tagline/catch phrase
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

$inputFilename    = 'input.csv';
$outputFilename   = 'output.xml';

// Open csv to read
$inputFile  = fopen($inputFilename, 'rt');

// Get the headers of the file
$headers = fgetcsv($inputFile);

// Create a new dom document with pretty formatting
$doc  = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->formatOutput   = true;

// Add a root node to the document
$root = $doc->createElement('rss');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
$root->setAttribute("version", "2.0");
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/' ,'xmlns:c', 'http://base.google.com/cns/1.0');

// Add channel node to the document
$channel = $doc->createElement('channel');
$root->appendChild($channel);

// Add title
$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$value = $doc->createCDATASection($storetitle);
$value = $title->appendChild($value);
$channel->appendChild($title);

// Add URL
$link = $doc->createElement('link');
$value = $doc->createCDATASection($url);
$value = $link->appendChild($value);
$channel->appendChild($link);

// Add description
$desc = $doc->createElement('description');
$value = $doc->createCDATASection($tagline);
$value = $desc->appendChild($value);
$channel->appendChild($desc);

// Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile)) !== FALSE)
{
    $container = $doc->createElement('item');
    foreach($headers as $i => $header)
    {
        if($row[4] == NULL){}
        else {      
            if($header == "id"){$child = $doc->createElement('g:id');}
            elseif($header == "name"){$child = $doc->createElement('title');}
            elseif($header == "caption"){$child = $doc->createElement('description');}
            elseif($header == "product-url"){$child = $doc->createElement('link');}
            elseif($header == "c4-tab5-local"){$child = $doc->createElement('g:product_type');}
            elseif($header == "c4-tab4-local"){$child = $doc->createElement('g:image_link');}
            elseif($header == "condition"){$child = $doc->createElement('g:condition');}
            elseif($header == "orderable"){$child = $doc->createElement('g:availability');}
            elseif($header == "price"){$child = $doc->createElement('g:price');}
            elseif($header == "sale-price"){$child = $doc->createElement('g:sale_price');}
            elseif($header == "code"){$child = $doc->createElement('g:mpn');}
            elseif($header == "label"){$child = $doc->createElement('g:brand');}
            elseif($header == "ship-weight"){$child = $doc->createElement('g:shipping');}
            else{$child = $doc->createElement($header);}

            $child = $container->appendChild($child);
            if ($header == "price" || $header == "sale-price"){$value = $doc->createCDATASection($row[$i] . " USD");}
            elseif ($header == "orderable"){
                if ($row[$i] == "Yes"){$value = $doc->createCDATASection('in stock');}
                else{$value = $doc->createCDATASection('out of stock');}
            }
            elseif ($header == "ship-weight"){
                $weight = $row[$i];

                $country = $doc->createElement('g:country');
                $value = $doc->createTextNode('US');
                $value = $country->appendChild($value);
                $child->appendChild($country);

                $method = $doc->createElement('g:service');
                $value = $doc->createTextNode('Ground');
                $value = $method->appendChild($value);
                $child->appendChild($method);

                $shipcost = $doc->createElement('g:price');
                if($weight <= "1"){$value = $doc->createTextNode('6.95 USD');}
                else{
                    $math = ceil($weight) *2 + 6.95;
                    $value = $doc->createTextNode($math . ' USD');
                }
                $value = $shipcost->appendChild($value);
                $child->appendChild($shipcost);
            }
            else{$value = $doc->createCDATASection($row[$i]);}
            $value = $child->appendChild($value);
        }
    }
    $channel->appendChild($container);
}

$strxml = $doc->saveXML();
$handle = fopen($outputFilename, "w");
fwrite($handle, $strxml);
fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: It turns out the foreach loop assigning $child for every createElement() was the issue. I changed it to use a unique variable for the element I needed to target and everything is working now. Can someone please mark this resolved or closed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you were able to solve the issue.  In general though, generating XML from CSV is quite difficult.  Google Shopping also accepts CSV files, so you can use a simple fgetcsv and fputcsv to remap the Yahoo catalog CSV export file.  Here's a brief sample to give you the idea:

```
// Read lines from Yahoo CSV file
while($row = fgetcsv($fp_in))
{
  // Strip HTML from caption
  $row[2] = strip_tags($row[2]);
  // Write line to Google Shopping CSV feed file
  fputcsv($fp_out);
}
```

For reference, you can read the code in this [Perl script to generate a Google Shopping feed for Yahoo Store](https://www.somacon.com/p167.php), and to validate your output against a professionally generated feed, you can try this [free Google Shopping feed generator for Yahoo Stores](https://www.atensoftware.com/p369.php).